# Tag merge: average and averages

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that there are both tags [average](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) and [averages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/averages).  Is there any subtle difference in meaning between the two?   That plural form of the tag doesn't have a tag wiki, so I'd suggest making it a synonym of [average](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) if it is redundant.

Comment: I agree. This is an excellent candidate for becoming a synonym. You can enter it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/average/synonyms), & we'll upvote the suggestion to make it a synonym.

Comment: Thanks @gung. I don't have enough reputation to suggest a tag synonym though.

Comment: What are you doing here?!?!?

Comment: @casperOne LOL! I have 67 accounts.  I am everywhere!  :)

Comment: We should have a contest to see who can earn more rep here =P

Comment: @casperOne Nerd Fight!  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have converted all occurrences of `averages` to `average`. They should now be synonyms in the future.